# MYSQL Join only on max row with data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, max

I have a query that selects properties, and I need to join them to get the most recent activity on each one, where that `activity_status = 3` (closed deal). when I get that, I need to get the bank that closed the deal (`banks.is_reward = 1`)

Problem is that the data is spread over many tables, so when I join to get all the results, and then try to limit to the `max(activity_date)`, I need to group the results, and then I don't get the correct data from the other columns.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e0627)

I can do

```
Select * from properties
join
(SELECT deal_properties.property_id, activity.deal_id, activity.activity_date, banks.bank_id
FROM deal_properties
JOIN activity on activity.deal_id = deal_properties.deal_id
AND activity.activity_status = 3
JOIN banks ON banks.deal_id = activity.deal_id
AND banks.is_rewarded = 1) a
on a.property_id = properties.property_id;
```

and that will get me all the closed properties, with the rewarded banks, but I cant seem to limit that by the `max(activity_date)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

The following gives what you're looking for following your current line of thought:

```
SELECT LastActivities.property_id, ActivityDetails.bank_id, LastActivities.activity_date 
FROM (
      SELECT p.property_id, MAX(a.activity_date) AS activity_date
      FROM properties p
      JOIN deal_properties dp
          ON dp.property_id = p.property_id
      JOIN activity a
          ON a.deal_id = dp.deal_id AND a.activity_status = 3
      GROUP BY p.property_id
) LastActivities

JOIN(
      SELECT a.activity_date, dp.property_id, b.bank_id 
      FROM deal_properties dp
      JOIN activity a
          ON a.deal_id = dp.deal_id AND a.activity_status = 3
      JOIN banks b
          ON b.deal_id = a.deal_id AND b.is_rewarded = 1
) ActivityDetails
  ON ActivityDetails.property_id = LastActivities.property_id 
  AND ActivityDetails.activity_date = LastActivities.activity_date
```

Here is the fiddle: [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5846e1/21)

**Option 2**

Below is another way to get the same results...  This should be a bit more efficient as it only has one derived table instead of two.

```
SELECT p.property_id, b.bank_id, a.activity_date
FROM activity a
JOIN banks b
  ON b.deal_id = a.deal_id AND b.is_rewarded = 1
JOIN deal_properties dp
  ON dp.deal_id = a.deal_id
JOIN properties p
  ON p.property_id = dp.property_id
JOIN(SELECT p.property_id, max(a.activity_date) AS activity_date
    FROM activity a
    JOIN deal_properties dp
      ON dp.deal_id = a.deal_id
    JOIN properties p
      ON p.property_id = dp.property_id
     GROUP BY p.property_id
) latest
  ON latest.activity_date = a.activity_date AND latest.property_id = p.property_id

WHERE a.activity_status = 3
```

Here is the fiddle for option 2: [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5846e1/41)

Comment: DarbyM, seems to work. I would prefer something more efficient, I will accept this if I can't find something better.

Comment: There is more efficient.. I just haven't finished polishing it.. I will update when finished.

Comment: Review Option 2...  It looks to be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, my actual use case was a little more complex, so I needed to tweak it a little, but this got me where I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your sample seems you need

```
Select * from properties p
inner join 
( SELECT deal_properties.property_id as property_id , max(activity.activity_date) max_date
  FROM deal_properties
  INNER JOIN activity on activity.deal_id = deal_properties.deal_id 
                   AND activity.activity_status = 3
  INNER JOIN banks ON banks.deal_id = activity.deal_id AND banks.is_rewarded = 1
  group by property_id
  ) a on  a.property_id = p.property_id;
```

Comment: scaisEdge, That works to get me the latest activity, but the issue as I mentioned is that I need the `bank_id` for that also, and when you do `group by property_id`, it does not get the correct bank_id. You can see this in the Fiddle I linked.

Comment: update  your question with a proper data sample and a coherent expected result

Comment: To get more details you can join this query with other tables.

Comment: See also window functions : Esp. Last value https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value

Comment: 1010 nice info on the Window Functions.  But if his "Fiddle" is any indicator, he is using MySQL 5.6   Window Functions aren't available until MySQL 8.